# Is it possible to open a page with a different theme?

Tags: themes

Is it possible to open a page (eg.: home) with a different theme?

The idea is to apply a different them to a page in particular. 
If yes, what would be the best way to achieve this?

- By capturing the request and temporarily changing the theme? The downside is that in concurrent calls things might get messy.
- By changing the current template and loading headers, etc from other theme? In this options you probably don't benefit from all the features the theme has to offer.
- another (probably better) option?

Comment: Simply change style for specific page. Without Header and footer

Comment: This plugin might do that for you: https://wordpress.org/plugins/jonradio-multiple-themes/

Answer (score 1):

Every solution to changing a theme on every click of **Home** button will result in many activation and deactivation requests. Some settings might get messed up for example widgets in the sidebars and menus etc on different theme activation. Also, it will require a proper setup in coding making current pages conditions in both themes.

The solution I came up with is that you install a new WordPress and setup new/2nd theme in a subdirectory named **home** under your parent installation directory.

After that, you can add a quick link to your parent/1st site's menu with "Home" label and set a link e.g `http://example2.com/home` to redirect on your 2nd site with a different theme. Now on the 2nd site, you can create the full menu with quick links pointing to the parent/1st site pages e.g `http://example.com/page-slug`.